# Is there any option to generate only request and response schema when using springdoc-openapi-ui?

Tags: swagger, openapi, springdoc, swagger-3.0, openapi-generator-cli

I'm using springdoc-openapi-ui at springboot project.
When i run the project and see the api-docs.json of swagger. There are all of dto schemas in my project.

i'll using this openapi spec file for generating client code.

Is there any option of making just request and response schema at springdoc-openapi ?
Or just put @Hidden annotations at the top of the class one by one is the only way to solve this problem?

If any best practice is exist please tell me.

To solve this problem, i read swagger and springdoc-openapi docs but i can't find about this...